# url rewrite with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've trying to rewrite my URL's but doesn't work as expected. This

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?currentpage=$1 [L]
should rewrite
http://site/index.php?currentpage=2 to-> http://site/2/
```

but nothing happen is still `http://site/index.php?currentpage=2`. Also this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /page.php?pn=$1 [L]
should rewrite http://site/page.php?pn=2 to-> http://site/2/
```

**This brake whole site and cause error 500**

Any idea why and what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a string starting and between values are not `/` and expects the last character to be `/` maybe try `^([^/]*)/?$` or `^([0-9]*)/?$`.

Comment: With first one `^([^/]*)/?$` I get 500 error, with second one `^([0-9]*)/?$` url is the same..

Comment: What's the exact url you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: You have it the wrong way around, that's not how rewrites work.

Comment: @deceze, what exactly is duplicated?

Comment: @Class, one of the url is `http://site/index.php?currentpage=2` where 2 is ID like `currentpage=$id`

Comment: Wait is this a `rewrite` or `redirect`?

Comment: a `rewrite` is where you have a url like `.../search/1` but it fetches `search.php?item=1` a `redirect` is where you have it the other way around but redirects you to a new page.

Comment: Have you *read* said linked duplicate? It explains your issue.

Comment: @deceze, I reading now.

Comment: @Class, as I'm not advanced in apache modrewrite I use online generator and when I enter the 'ugly' url every generator gave me `Rewrite` not `redirect`.. thats why I think for `rewrite`. Another generator gave me this `RewriteRule /currentpage/(.*)/ index.php?currentpage=$1` and again nothing

Comment: @deceze, yes my issue is there but I don't saw a solution since I've tried what is said there. So thats why I think is not duplicated since it doesn't really help me.

Comment: It should at least fix your fundamental misunderstanding. If you still have problems implementing a solution based on this new understanding, show your new attempt. The code you currently show *cannot* work the way you want it to.

Comment: Ok, one thing I don't understand why I need `redirect` and not `rewrite` since I _rewrite_ the URL. I've readed [this](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls) and many more and everwehere they write about `rewrite`

Comment: Who says you need "redirect"?

Comment: So I'm again misunderstood. Now I've trying on link `<a href='/currentpage/$nextpage'>` and in .htaccess `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?currentpage=$1` and I get next value with good URL but no css on page or 404 page not found

Comment: Great, so that's fixed now. Depending on how you've embedded your CSS, its relative URL has probably changed, since the URL is different now. Look at your browser's development debug/network tools to see what URLs it tries to use and change them accordingly.

Comment: `Request URL:http://mysite/currentpage/2` -> `Page Not Found`

Comment: Now is work but doesn't load a .css file. As I can see it's trying to load css from `/index/currentpage/2/include/style.css`. On the server css file is in `/include/style.css`

Comment: It's done. I simply put one `/` where I include `style.css` so now is `/include/style.css` instead of `include/style.css`. Now is working as expected. Thank's for help guys!

Comment: So you have it working so `http://site/index.php?currentpage=2` to-> `http://site/2/`?

Comment: Do you want post how you solved it as an answer (and then mark it as correct) so other people with the same problem as you, will know how you solved it?

Comment: Ok, I will post it. Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used links like this to go on next or prev page

```
// Prev page
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'>

// Next page
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>
```

I didn't understand it right at first and tryed to make changes only in `.htaccess` file but then I've read that there is no way to happen if I don't change also `hrefs` so I've change them like this

```
// Prev page
<a href='/currentpage/$prevpage/'>

// Next page
<a href='/currentpage/$nextpage/'>
```

in `.htaccess` file I put this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^currentpage/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?currentpage=$1 [L]
```

and now when I change pages is like `http:/website.com/currentpage/2/`

Please correct me if there is something else that is wrong but so far is working as expected. Thank's for help!

**UPDATE**

I've forget about that when I've made this changes I've made also changes on path to my `style.css` and other images/js etc. files. What I mean is before I used to include `style.css` this way `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/style.css">` after change the urls in order to get proper path must add one lead slash (/) so it become `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/include/style.css">`. Also added to other elements..